# android post JSONArray get String response with volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to send JSONArray to server and get String as response using volley request. But JsonArrayRequest response JsonArray this is my code.

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            System.out.println("Response------> " + response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("VolleyError-------> " + volleyError);
        }
    });
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

How can i do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, and you want to have String beside JsonArray, just use as you have in your example, `toString()` method

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    System.out.println("Response------> " + response.toString());
    String strValue = response.toString(); // here is String value
}
```